# BeautifulSoup webscraper issue: can't find certain divs/tables

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having issues with scraping pro-football-reference.com. I'm trying to access the "Team Offense" table but can't seem to target the div/table.
The best I can do is:

```
soup.find('div', {'id':'all_team_stats})
```

which doesn't return the table nor it's immediate div wrapper. The following attempts return "None":

```
soup.find('div', {'id':'div_team_stats'})
soup.find('table', {'id':'team_stats'})
```

I've already scraped different pages simply by:

```
soup.find('table', {'id':'table_id})
```

but I can't figure out why it's not working on this page. Below is the code I've been working with. Any help is much appreciated!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def make_soup(url):
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
    return soupdata

def get_player_totals():
    soup = make_soup("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2015/")

    tableStats = soup.find('table', {'id':'team_stats'})

    return tableStats

print get_player_totals()
```

EDIT:

Thanks for all the help everyone. Both of the provided solutions below have been successful. Much appreciated!

Comment: The table is commented out.

Comment: immediately below the commented out section, there are a couple of divs in div.table_outer_container.mobile_table with classes div_team_stats_clone and div_team_stats that have the table I need. Are these divs hidden or something?

Comment: When I looked in the page source, found only one div called all_team_stats and that could be extracted.

Comment: Just remove the comments and parse

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the comments with *re.sub* before you pass to bs4:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
comm = re.compile("<!--|-->")
def make_soup(url):
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(comm.sub("", page.read()), 'lxml')
    return soupdata

def get_player_totals():
    soup = make_soup("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2015/")

    tableStats = soup.find('table', {'id':'team_stats'})

    return tableStats

print get_player_totals()
```

You will see the table when you run the code.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of thoughts here: first, as mentioned in the comments, the acutal table is commented out and is not *per se* part of the `DOM` (not accessible via a parser adhoc).
In this situation, you can loop over the comments found and try to get the information via regular expressions (though this heavily discussed and mostly disliked on Stackoverflow, [**see here for more information**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)). Last, but not least, I would recommend [**`requests`**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) rather than `urllib2`.

That being said, here is a working code example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import requests, re

def make_soup(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2015/")

# get the comments
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))

# look for table with the id "team_stats"
rx = re.compile(r'<table.+?id="team_stats".+?>[\s\S]+?</table>')
for comment in comments:
    try:
        table = rx.search(comment.string).group(0)
        print(table)
        # break the loop if found
        break
    except:
        pass
```

**Always** favour a parser solution over this one, especially the regex part is very error-prone.